# Simple_form as: :currency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Want to format text in the input field as currency. Found [this](http://bentoncreation.com/post/134874453155/custom-currency-input-for-simple-form) solution.
So input builder look like this:

```
  def input_group(currency, merged_input_options)
    "#{@builder.text_field(attribute_name, merged_input_options)} #{currency_addon(currency)}".html_safe
  end
```

But I still need forcing decimal format of a value:

```
= f.input :price, as: :currency, input_html: { value: number_with_precision(f.object.price, precision: 2) }
```

Is it possible to improve builder than it could format number to decimal itself?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need `def input group` to return a float value? If so, have you tried simply `to_f`? http://apidock.com/ruby/String/to_f

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, here is a fully functional example. HTML classes are matching use of Bootstrap 5 style, and Simple Form is configured to use HTML 5 variants.

To use the new input as

```rb
  f.input :price, as: :currency
```

Put it in `app/lib/simple_form/inputs/currency_input.rb`

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

module SimpleForm
  module Inputs
    class CurrencyInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::Base
      include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper

      def input(wrapper_options)
        currency = options.delete(:currency) || default_currency
        wrapper_options = wrapper_options.merge(
          value: number_with_precision(@builder.object.send(attribute_name) / 100.0, precision: 2),
          type: "number",
          step: 1,
          lang: "#{I18n.locale}",
        )
        merged_input_options = merge_wrapper_options(input_html_options, wrapper_options)

        content_tag(:div, input_group(currency, merged_input_options), class: "input-group")
      end

      private

      def input_group(currency, merged_input_options)
        "#{@builder.text_field(attribute_name, merged_input_options)} #{currency_addon(currency)} ".html_safe
      end

      def currency_addon(currency)
        content_tag(:span, currency, class: "input-group-text")
      end

      def default_currency
        "€"
      end
    end
  end
end
```